# What do difficulty levels do in Superman 64?

Tags: superman-64

The options menu of Superman 64 includes three difficulty levels: Easy Mode, Normal Mode, and Superman Mode.

I know from [watching speedruns](https://youtu.be/EiAYP6P_lJo) that ring stages are skipped when playing on Easy, but I don’t know how else the modes differ.

What changes between each difficulty level in Superman 64?

Comment: It for sure doesnt make the game suck less.

Comment: What in the world... why would people speed run this game?  It's like doing a Guinness world record for the longest butt floss with barbed wire...